# How to store output of a SQL Server stored procedure in a .txt file

Tags: sql-server

I have this stored procedure; I am printing the value of the variable in SSMS. 
Instead, I want to store this result in a `.txt` file.

NOTE: I don't want to do it using SSMS options of right clicking on the result and then saving the result as. I want it to be done using any SQL code/built-in function directly in the stored procedure itself.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_printresulttofile]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    SET @var = 'print this data in txt file'

    PRINT 'Data is : ' + @var   
    /* SQL query here to store result of Print statement in text file */
END

EXEC [dbo].[usp_printresulttofile]
```

Sharing the updated working SP here so that it might be useful to someone with a similar requirement  Thanks @David Browne - Microsoft

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_printresulttofile]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @fileTimeStamp varchar(200) =  convert(varchar,getDate(), 112 )+'_'+ Replace(convert(varchar,getDate(), 114 ),':','')  -- select convert(varchar, getdate(), 121)

    DECLARE @fileExtension varchar(5) = 'txt'
    DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    SET @var = 'print this data in txt file'
    PRINT 'Data is : ' + @var   


  declare @fn varchar(500) = 'c:/log/SP_output_'+@fileTimeStamp+'.'+@fileExtension;
    declare @cmd varchar(8000) = concat('echo ', @var, ' > "', @fn, '"');

    print @cmd 
    exec xp_cmdshell @cmd,  no_output

    set @cmd  = concat('type "', @fn, '"');

    print @cmd 
    exec xp_cmdshell @cmd;

    END
    GO
```

Comment: At best you'll be able to write to a file that is on the server where SQL Server is running (or a share accessible from this server), which the SQL Server service account has permission to access.  It's not impossible - you can run external scripts from SQL Server - but not very useful.

Comment: @Joe Yes that's exactly what I want to do I want to write results to a file and its location is a UNC share path. The server does have permissions to access this path.

Comment: In that case, you can use one of the methods supported by SQL Server, e.g. xp_cmdshell, SQL Server CLR integration, ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the comments and other answers indicate, this is not usually a good idea.  But here's how to do it anyway, assuming you're a sysadmin on SQL Server. :)

```
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.  
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
-- To enable the feature.  
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_printresulttofile]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    SET @var = 'print this data in txt file'
    PRINT 'Data is : ' + @var   

    declare @fn varchar(200) = 'c:\temp\out.txt';

    declare @cmd varchar(8000) = concat('echo ', @var, ' > "', @fn, '"');

    print @cmd 
    exec xp_cmdshell @cmd,  no_output

    set @cmd  = concat('type "', @fn, '"');

    print @cmd 
    exec xp_cmdshell @cmd;


END
go
EXEC [dbo].[usp_printresulttofile]
```

Comment: Thanks @David Browne - Microsoft This is exactly what I wanted, Just one thing is missing every time I execute the SP it overrides the text file. Instead, I want it to append files for each run. Can this be done?

Comment: Change ‘>’ to ‘>>’ to append instead of replace.

Comment: When I said I don't want to override files means for every execution of SP new text file should be created in the same location. Adding >> appended results in the same text.  However, i got it done. By making some minor changes to your SP.

Answer (score 4):

I might recommend creating a batch file to accomplish this.  You can simply do this:

```
sqlcmd -i ExecSQLProc.sql > Results.txt
```

Save your EXEC command in a file named `ExecSQLProc.sql` and then create a batch script with the line above. You can also attach this to the scheduler if needed so that you can regularly generate these scripts.  Also you can create a process to output whatever your process produces into an email using only SQL server and see the results this way as well.

Generally I have found it better to use the Operating System to manipulate individual files, if you want to append results you have options:

1. `sqlcmd -i ExecSQLProc.sql >> CumulativeResults.txt`
2. Update your stored process to keep track of your data in the database that is a large container - a blob for instance, and then when you execute your script it will generate a file that has everything in it.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @Turner But my requirement is SP itself should have logic to write data to a file whenever SP is executed rather than creating a batch and then executing that batch.

Comment: Please indicate how your stored process is scheduled and I can try to help you figure that out too! =)

Comment: its not scheduled. Basically, I am going to call SP in ETL tool and I want to log results of SP in a file whenever that SP is called.

Comment: Maybe create two processes if you want to really boil things down and get intimate details about each execution - for example, you can create a trigger that fires when your ETL package makes an insert somewhere and then you can use the trigger to populate execution times (for example) in a table along with other metrics you are looking at.  SSIS allows you to fire triggers (depending on what driver you use) and a second stored process could be used to grab the rows you need and put those in a txt file via the above method and also mark them as 'written' to a file.

Comment: And almost certainly this should be a part of your ETL process. But your procedure code is trivial and gives no clues about your goal. You will see this more clearly when you need to modify the ETL logic and forget about the procedure and its hard-coded path. You will also likely forget about this dependency when you move/migrate (or install another instance) of your system. I suggest you read about cohesion and coupling in software.

Comment: the batch process can be made dynamic if he needs to work in different environments, this is easy, assuming the structure of a dev/test/prod setup would have structures in parallel (which they should)  Having a text file that contains this information is what I am not sure I 100% understand, execution metrics can be stored in a table in SQL server for example (assuming this is what we are storing) and having regularly emailed reports is also an option.  The batch script as well as the processes can be automated.

Comment: @smor I would not necessarily create an ETL process that takes data and writes it to a file in a filesystem as opposed to a database.  I am not sure if this is what you mean above, but SSIS for example is built to interface with databases specifically and not text files and is most efficiently employed working with databases.  Building a separate process to digest data and update the file system would be the correct answer in my mind because it could execute asynchronously and it won't impact the speed of moving data over from one ETL endpoint to another.

Answer (score 2):

Use bcp command to copy data into any format. You just need to mention the format in which you want. Like .text

bcp 'select * from table' queryout c:\sql\bcp.txt -c -T

Example and explaination in below link :-
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4353/export-sql-server-records-into-individual-text-files/

Answer (score 0):

Just remember to be careful with the string going to the text file.  If it has quotes / double quotes, etc. it will affect its ability to save.  I automatically put double quotes around my outgoing string and it typically helps but if your string is more complicated (i.e. a SQL query with literal comparisons) then you likely will have more work to do.